# Mysql. Бесконечный INSERT данных

Tags: mysql

Столкнулся внезапно с такой проблемой.

Есть таблица, в которой есть данные. Процедура удаляет необходимые данные из этой таблицы и рассчитывает их заново(INSERT). Использую INSERT SELECT. И тут начинаются проблемы. Возьмем ситуацию, когда в таблице есть данные, но все они удаляются.
   Если из таблицы все данные удаляются через DELETE, то при первом INSERT происходит зависание. Но если убить процесс и запустить процедуру заново, то все выполнится. И так все время повторяется.
   Если очистить таблицу через TRUNCATE, то процедура выполняется с первого раза.

Попробовал установить в конфиге: innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M. После этого перестало зависать на INSERT. Хотел для 100% уверенности еще прогнать процедуру
без этого параметра, но теперь без него MYSQL отказывается стартовать.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этим вопросом. Очень интересно.

Пример:

```
 /*Разбиваю входящий массив id на записи в таблице(Делаю из массива таблицу)*/
CALL explode(',', changed_ids, 'tmp_ids4educontrol', 'id', 'INT');

/*Удаляю данные из edu_control, которые будут пересчитываться*/
DELETE edu4_control FROM edu4_control JOIN tmp_ids4educontrol 
WHERE ((changed_id_type = 'did') AND (edu4_control.did = tmp_ids4educontrol.id))
OR ((changed_id_type = 'pid') AND (edu4_control.pid = tmp_ids4educontrol.id));

/*Добавляю записи*/
INSERT INTO edu4_control(company_id, pid, did, title, courses, courses_ids, nextdate, adate_last, adate_next, position_id)
SELECT ... FROM (несколько таблиц.);
```

Comment: Не найдётся ли у вас какого-нибудь простенького примера кода, который продемонстрировал бы зависание? С ним обсуждение было бы продуктивнее

Comment: Вы описываете типичное поведение при deadlock-е.

Comment: А из-за чего может взаимная блокировка появляться? В INSERT в SELECT я не обращаюсь к таблице, в которую добавляются данные.

Comment: И почему при повторном запуске процедуры deadlock не происходит, а truncate вообще исключает?

Comment: И чем установка innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M изменила поведение INSERT ?

Comment: Я не знаю, как в mysql организовано запирание таблиц/страниц/записей в пределах транзакций. Но, судя по Вашему описанию, таблица оказывается запертой из-за предшествующего DELETE-a, и INSERT ждет, пока этот "запор" не будет снят.

Comment: Если Deleted завершился, то как может блокировка не сниматься?

Comment: Нашел, откуда проблема начинается. В DELETE и В INSERT SELECT используется одна и та же временная таблица.

Answer (score 0):

С таблицы, в которую вы всё время только вставляете текст снимайте все(!) дополнительные ключи, кроме одного primary.

Их создание, кэширование и т.п. жрёт время, помимо самих действий над данными,  а оно тут никак не выигрывается потом селектами... как я понимаю описание.

Файлы ключей(и файл самой таблицы) растут, delete их не уменьшает. Файлы ключей могут ничего толком не содержать(и файл самой таблицы), но быть уже эпических размеров.

периодически делайте repair или optimize table

теред bulk insert вообще ключи и на нормальных таблицах неплохо бы временно сносить.

по идее только в такой ситуации вам может помогать манипуляция с innodb_buffer_pool_size. но не долго.